# Show an alert in one page if in a second page change an input

Tags: php, jquery

I have this scenario:

I've a web app in php/jquery.

The page is divided by an horizontal header at the top (with main menu, and a Company switch) and the primary content.

With the Company switch I can operate by the company actually "loggedin", saving my ID in the `$_SESSION['company_ID']` using php ON EVERY OPENED PAGE.

For example I have:

- Company One with `ID = 1`
- Company Two with `ID = 2`

When i submit a form, I'll save all my data from the form and also save `company_ID` in my db, reading the value from the `$_SESSION['company_ID']`

The problem is where I open 2 web pages on the same browser:

1. first page opened, and logged as ID = 1
2. open a second page on the same browser, and change the company to Company Two with ID = 2
3. return to first already opened page and submit the form. if i'll submit, I get my $_SESSION['company_ID'] wrong, cause I opened the second page after the first and I switched the company. In this case I get ID = 2 (wrong) instead of ID = 1.

My question is: is possible to send an javascript `alert("Attention: ID changed, don't submit the form")` 
when i get focus on the first page to prevent this problem? Is it possible to send a "trigger" to another page from one page? Or is there a better way to prevent this problem?

Comment: Did you think about using cookies?

Comment: You would have to use "polling", which isn't really ideal, to checked if you are still "logged in" with the selected ID every X seconds.  But I'd question your whole logic of saving the ID in session on selection change and relying on the session value in the first place.  Why not just submit the ID with the form submit and use that value on each submit.  What really is the point of the session here?

Comment: @PatrickQ I followed the polling solution and it works greats. I can't change to the new login to insert the ID in the form cause I've a lot of pages with form so I don't want to spend much times to edit all pages. I use session to operate with permission on each page (view, edit forms) based on ID user loggedin and ID of the company selected.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I can think of is to use a hidden input.

When you load the form include something like:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="company_id" value="1" />
```

Then on submission, check if the `$_SESSION['company_id']` matches `$_POST['company_id']` and if it doesn't, then return an error & do not submit the form data to your database.

Comment: Yes I've already thinked about this solution. But I'd like to "dinamically" alert the user BEFORE submit or do any action in the "old" page opened

Comment: Okay. I think you could use [onfocus](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp) on the body tag or maybe the form and [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp). So when the onfocus happens on the form, you could send a request to the server with the original company id (from the hidden input, or stored in a js variable) and have the server respond based upon whether the company id matches or not.

Comment: There might be another javascript event which would be better to use. And there might be an entirely better way to go about it, but idk.